# How to find PID by application name using shell command

Tags: python, ubuntu

I started a python program and send it to the background.

```
$: python myapp.py &
```

Then I closed the terminal and forgot the PID it returned. Now I would like to kill that program, the only clue I left is the program name `myapp.py`. How can I find the PID using shell command?

Comment: see [How to find the Process ID (PID) of a running terminal program?](https://askubuntu.com/q/180336/301745) on Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way:
Try `ps -ef | grep myapp.py` to find the PID, Then kill it.

Another way is:
Try `pkill -f myapp.py` to kill it by its name.

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks

Comment: @Xer Good, Remember to accept the answer and upvote haha~

Comment: Sure, it only allows to do so after 10 minutes,